# Как написать свой аллокатор?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-faq

Часто пишут что с не-стандартным аллокатором код может работать быстрее, а как вообще написать свой аллокатор?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Требования к аллокаторам, и их значения по-умолчанию приведены в главе *"Allocator requirements [allocator.requirements]"*. В этой же главе приводится пример минимального аллокатора:

```
template <class Tp>
struct SimpleAllocator {
    typedef Tp value_type;
    SimpleAllocator(аргументы конструктора);

    template <class T> SimpleAllocator(const SimpleAllocator<T>& other);

    Tp* allocate(std::size_t n);
    void deallocate(Tp* p, std::size_t n);
};

template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const SimpleAllocator<T>&, const SimpleAllocator<U>&);
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const SimpleAllocator<T>&, const SimpleAllocator<U>&);
```

Предполагается, что контейнеры обязаны обращаться к аллокатору не напрямую, а через шаблон `std::allocator_traits`, который предоставляет значения по-умолчанию, такие как `typedef T* pointer;`, и т.п.

Однако **существующие реализации стандартных библиотек не везде используют `allocator_traits`**.
По этому если мы попробуем например скомпилировать код
`std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, SimpleAllocator<char>> s;`
то мы получим такие ошибки:

```
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/basic_string.h:114:41: error: 'rebind' following the 'template' keyword does not refer to a template
  typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_CharT>::other _CharT_alloc_type;
```

или

```
1>S:\MSVS2013\VC\include\xstring(664): error C2903: 'rebind' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
```

В обоих случаях в реализации стандартной библиотеки написано `_Alloc::rebind` вместо `allocator_traits<_Alloc>::rebind`.

Таким образом, при написании своего аллокатора, надо смотреть на ошибки компиляции, и при необходимости дописывать нужные члены класса.

Ниже приведен пример Arena аллокатора, который компилируется (VC++2013, g++-4.9.2)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

class Arena {
public:
    Arena() {}
    ~Arena() {
        assert(m_allocations == 0);
    }

    void* allocate(std::size_t n) {
        if (n > m_available) {
            m_chunks.emplace_back(100500);
            m_available = m_chunks.back().size();
            m_memory = &m_chunks.back().front();
        }

        auto mem = m_memory;
        m_available -= n;
        m_memory += n;
        ++m_allocations;
        return mem;
    }
    void deallocate(void* p, std::size_t n) {
        --m_allocations;
        auto mem = (unsigned char*)p;
        if (mem + n == m_memory) {
            m_memory = mem;
            m_available += n;
        }
    }

private:
    std::deque<std::vector<unsigned char>> m_chunks;
    std::size_t m_available = 0;
    unsigned char* m_memory;
    int m_allocations = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct ArenaAllocator {
    using value_type = T;

    using Traits = std::allocator_traits<ArenaAllocator<T>>;

#if !defined _MSC_VER    
    // libstdc++ использует конструктор по умолчанию:
    // __a == _Alloc()
    ArenaAllocator() : m_arena(nullptr) {}

    // libstdc++ требует следующие определения
    using size_type = typename std::allocator<T>::size_type;
    using difference_type = typename std::allocator<T>::difference_type;
    using pointer = typename std::allocator<T>::pointer;
    using const_pointer = typename std::allocator<T>::const_pointer;
    // "reference" не входит Allocator Requirements,
    // но libstdc++ думает что она всегда работает с std::allocator.
    using reference = typename std::allocator<T>::reference;
    using const_reference = typename std::allocator<T>::const_reference;
#endif

    explicit ArenaAllocator(Arena& arena) : m_arena(&arena) {}
    template<class U> ArenaAllocator(const ArenaAllocator<U>& other) : m_arena(other.m_arena) {}

    T* allocate(std::size_t n) { return (T*)m_arena->allocate(n * sizeof(T)); }
    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) { m_arena->deallocate(p, n * sizeof(T)); }

    // требуется в VC++ и libstdc++
    template<class U, class... Args> void construct(U* p, Args&&... args) { std::allocator<T>().construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
    template<class U> void destroy(U* p) { std::allocator<T>().destroy(p); }
    template<class U> struct rebind { using other = ArenaAllocator<U>; };

    Arena* m_arena;
};

template<class T, class U> bool operator==(const ArenaAllocator<T>& lhs, const ArenaAllocator<U>& rhs) { return lhs.m_arena == rhs.m_arena; }
template<class T, class U> bool operator!=(const ArenaAllocator<T>& lhs, const ArenaAllocator<U>& rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }

#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using a_string = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, ArenaAllocator<char>>;

template <class T> using a_vector = std::vector<T, ArenaAllocator<T>>;
template <class T> using a_deque= std::deque<T, ArenaAllocator<T>>;
template <class T> using a_list = std::list<T, ArenaAllocator<T>>;
template <class K> using a_set = std::set<K, std::less<K>, ArenaAllocator<K>>;
template <class K, class V> using a_map = std::map<K, V, std::less<K>, ArenaAllocator<std::pair<const K, V>>>;
template <class K> using a_unordered_set = std::unordered_set<K, std::hash<K>, std::equal_to<K>, ArenaAllocator<K>>;
template <class K, class V> using a_unordered_map = std::unordered_map<K, std::hash<K>, std::equal_to<K>, ArenaAllocator<std::pair<const K, V>>>;

struct X {};

int main() {
    Arena arena;
    ArenaAllocator<char> arena_allocator(arena);

    a_string s_empty(arena_allocator);
    a_string s_123("123", arena_allocator);

    a_vector<int> v_int({1, 2, 3}, arena_allocator);
    a_vector<X> v_x(42, X{}, arena_allocator);
    a_vector<a_string> v_str({s_empty, s_123}, arena_allocator);
    a_vector<a_string> v_str_copy(v_str, arena_allocator);
    a_deque<int> d_int({1, 2, 3}, arena_allocator);
    a_list<int> l_int({1, 2, 3}, arena_allocator);
    a_set<int> s_int({1, 2, 3}, std::less<int>{}, arena_allocator);
    a_map<a_string, int> m_str_int(arena_allocator);
    a_unordered_set<int> us_int(arena_allocator);

    auto p = std::allocate_shared<int>(arena_allocator, 123);

#if 0 // этот код не работает в VC++ и g++
    a_unordered_map<a_string, int> um_str_int(arena_allocator); 
    std::function<void()> f(std::allocator_arg_t{}, arena_allocator, []{});
#endif
}
```

Comment: Вот это да, круто!

Comment: assert(m_allocations == 0) - я так понимаю это для отладки?
А если например будет вызвано одинаковое количество allocate и deallocate, но с разными n, что тогда будет в этом случае?

Comment: действительно круто, искал тему по аллокаторам и на такую классную штуку наткнулся!