# Аллокаторы памяти

Tags: c++, c, память

Не так давно услышал о том, что существует способ управлять памятью самому, а не использовать, например, `new` и  `delete`. Может кто-нибудь сможет осветить эту тему поподробнее, и привести какой-нибудь пример кода на С или С++, так как в интернете нашел мало информации на эту тему.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419395/317064

Comment: А что Вас конкретно интересует? Есть много способов управления памятью помимо new и delete. Выше, вот, дали ссылку на написание своего аллокатора. Рекомендую почитать так же про идиому RAII :  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Из внешних аллокаторов заслуживает внимания `llalloc` https://locklessinc.com/articles/allocator_tricks/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Прежде всего, почему динамическое управление памятью медленное занятие:

1. Выделение памяти при помощи стандартных библиотечных функций обычно требует звонков в ядро, думаю все прекрасно понимают, что эта операция является не совсем быстрой.
2. Нет никакого способа узнать, где та память, которую вернёт вам malloc или new, будет находиться по отношению к другим областям памяти в вашем приложении, в связи с этим получается значительная фрагментация памяти, да и к тому же будет больше промахов в кеше.

В связи с этим появляется некая сущность под названием **Аллокатор**, способная ускорить этот процесс. На самом деле, существуют множество различных способов реализации аллокаторов(линейный, блочный, стековый и т.д.), но в качестве примера ограничимся только линейным, в силу того, что он наиболее простой в реализации и понятный для осознания самой концепции *ручного управления памяти*. Идея состоит в том, чтобы сохранить указатель на первый адрес памяти вашего блока памяти и перемещать его каждый раз, когда выделение завершено. В этом аллокаторе внутренняя фрагментация сведена к минимуму, потому что все элементы вставляются последовательно (пространственная локальность) и единственная фрагментация между ними - выравнивание. Однако из-за своей простоты данный аллокатор не позволяет освободить определенные позиции памяти, обычно вся память освобождается вместе. Итак приступим, в качестве примера возьмем всем хорошо знакомый язык С

```
struct linear_allocator_t
{
    void* base_pointer;
    size_t size;
    size_t offset;
};

typedef struct linear_allocator_t linear_allocator_t;
```

Создаем структуру, которая имеет несколько полей: *base_pointer*  - указатель на выделенный участок памяти при помощи стандартной библиотечной функций, *size* - размер выделенной памяти, *offset* - смещение, относительно последнего выделения памяти, уже нашим собственным аллокатором.

```
int la_init(linear_allocator_t* allocator, size_t memory_size)
{
    if (memory_size == 0)
        return 0;

    allocator->offset = 0;
    allocator->size = memory_size;
    allocator->base_pointer = malloc(memory_size);
    return allocator->base_pointer != NULL;
} 

void la_allocate(linear_allocator_t* allocator, size_t allocated_size)
{
    // Проверяем на достаточное количество памяти для выделения
    if (allocator->offset + allocated_size > allocator->size)
        return NULL;

    // Проверяем на не нулевой размер и на выравнивание
    if ( (allocated_size == 0) || (allocator->size % allocated_size != 0) )
        return NULL;

    size_t allocated_pointer = (size_t) allocator->base_pointer + allocator->offset;
    allocator->offset += allocated_size;
    return (void*) allocated_pointer;
}

// Данный аллокатор не поддерживает данную операцию(функция добавлена в качестве пояснения о существовании текущей операции)
void la_free(linear_allocator_t* allocator, void* pointer)
{
    assert(false && "Current allocator does not support current method. Use la_reset()");
}

void la_reset(linear_allocator_t* allocator)
{
    free(allocator->base_pointer);
}
```

Ну и напоследок само использование нашего аллокатора в действии:

```
// Тестовая структура, только для проверки
struct vector_4d_t
{
    double x, y, z, w;
};

typedef struct vector_4d_t vector_4d_t;

int main()
{
    // В данном примере фрагментация отсутствует
    linear_allocator_t allocator;
    la_init(&allocator, sizeof(vector_4d_t) * 100);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        vector_4d_t* vector = (vector_4d_t*) la_allocate(&allocator, sizeof(vector_4d_t));
        vector->x = vector->y = vector->z = vector->w = i;
    }
    la_reset(&allocator);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Надеюсь, что мой ответ оказался вам полезным!

Comment: `size_t allocated_pointer = (std::size_t) allocator->base_pointer + allocated_size;` наверное хотели все же добавлять `allocator->offset`? Ну и с "валидным" выравниванием как-то странно (мягко говоря...).

Comment: Да, спасибо за замечание

Comment: Поясните все же, в чем смысл выражения `(allocator->size % allocated_size != 0)`, которое позволяет запрашивать куски лишь кратные выделенной памяти? (например, если `allocator->size = 1024 * 1024` (1Mbyte), то запросить можно только степень двойки, а вот 100 байт нельзя)

Answer (score 11):

Функциональность оператора `new` фактически сводится к

1. Вызову функции выделения "сырой" памяти требуемого размера
2. Инициализации объекта в этой "сырой" памяти

Никто вам не запрещает выполнять эти шаги самостоятельно: выделять "сырую" память любым удобным для вас способом, а затем инициализировать объект в этой памяти при помощи placement-new

```
// Создание объекта типа `T`
void *raw = my_malloc(sizeof(T)); // <- любой способ выделения памяти
T *pt = new(raw) T(параметры);    // <- инициализация объекта
```

При выделении памяти в общем случае следует позаботиться не только об ее размере, но и о соблюдении требований выравнивания.

Удаление объекта повторяет функциональность оператора `delete`, т.е. делается через синтаксис вызова псевдо-деструктора и вашу же функцию освобождения "сырой" памяти

```
pt->~T();
my_free(pt);
```

Вот и все.

А если ваша задача выходит за рамки функциональности голого `new` и `delete`, и, например, предполагает создание своих аллокаторов для стандартных контейнеров, то это уже несколько другая история.

Comment: В замене слова new используется слово new...

Comment: @Philippe: Это синтаксис `placement-new`. Обратите внимание на круглые скобки с аргументом `raw` внутри. Это совсем не то, что "обычное" `new`.

Comment: А с помощью `__attribute __ ((cleanup (x)))` (gcc,clang) можно делать собственные умные переменные, на подобии `unique_ptr`, в добавление к собственной реализации new. И собственный аллокатор ИМХО имеет смысл писать с учётом сборщика мусора, в этом ещё есть какой-то смысл.

Comment: Не надо в C++ делать "умные переменные" через `__attrbiute__((cleanup(fn)))`, это костыль для C, потому что там нем деструкторов. Идиома в C++ называется [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).